# Filtering keyup events which produce a character

Tags: javascript, html

I need to only track `keyup` events for keys which produce a character. The reason I need `keyup` (which tracks all keys) over `keypress` (which tracks only those that produce a character) is because my logic has to run *after* the character has appeared in the DOM.

My logic styles content as it's added to `contenteditable` (TinyMCE) but I can't do that on `keypress` because the content hasn't actually been added yet.

The MDN documentation for [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) mention the `char` property which sounds like it does what I want, but at least in Chrome, it's always `undefined`.

I need to support IE10+, modern Chrome/Firefox, if that matters.

Comment: have you tried using `charCode` instead of `char`?

Comment: If you provide a working code snippet, you might get some proper answers, as of now it is not clear what it is that is not working.

Comment: Use the `key` property instead of `char`, it's supported from IE9 upwards: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#Browser_compatibility

Comment: `key` doesn't inherently differentiate between character and non-character keys, I'd have to compile a whitelist which I'm hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 5):

You can check if the key pressed was a character using a regular expression.

```
function(e) {
  if (e.key.match(/^[a-zA-Z]$/g)) {
     // Do something with character
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a whitelist for they key codes which produce the characters you are okay with, and then compare the current key code from the keyup event to your whitelist.

Alternatively, you could also track the innerText of the element, and then compare the difference on keyup in order to see what was entered.

All in all, keyup will still improperly catch the scenario of pasted content, and any inspection of the key code or char will inevitably become tedious without a whitelist given the current popularity of emojies.

While this may take a small amount of time to compose up front, the time and headaches it will prevent in the future are well worth it.